# How to convert uploaded file from charset=iso-8859-1 to charset=utf-8?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

When user uploads a file that has charset=iso-8859-1 it comes with question marks and gibberish.

I have seen that there online web converts it successfully to utf-8 - so after uploading the file after this conversion the file is getting uploaded properly. This is the web: https://subtitletools.com/convert-text-files-to-utf8-online

This is my code:

```
const file = document.getElementById('some-id').files[0];

const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = event => {
  let data = event.target.result;
  console.log(`[data]:`, data); // question marks / gibberish
}

reader.readAsText(file);
```

I have also tried to use `reader.readAsBinaryString` but got gibberish instead of question marks.

I have also tried to use the utf8 library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8 but it didn't work.

How the site that I mentioned above achieves to convert the file to the desired charset so its data is not in question marks or gibberish? BTW also Google Drive does it well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encoding_API/Encodings) with you own charset

```
var data = new TextDecoder('iso-8859-1').decode(await file.arrayBuffer())
```

guess the harder part is to figure out what charset it's

If you are not using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) then you can instead do this:

```js
const file = document.getElementById('some-id').files[0];
file.arrayBuffer().then(ab => {
  const data = new TextDecoder('iso-8859-1').decode(ab)
})
```

Comment: From where is the: `await file.arrayBuffer()` ?

Comment: updated the example to include non await code example

Comment: No problem with async await, problem is that arrayBuffer is an undefined method.

Comment: Probably using a very old browser then, in that case use `filereader.readAsArrayBuffer` And update you browser (ditch IE)